# Реализация разности соседних элементов массива

Tags: c++, массивы, пузырьковая-сортировка

> Дана на выполнение задача:
>   Дан  одномерный  массив  с  N
>   элементами. Отсортировать массив в
>   порядке  возрастания.  Затем
>   сформировать  новый  массив,
>   элементами  которого  являются
>   разности соседних элементов.

Реализовал пузырьковую сортировку:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int *arr; // указатель для выделения памяти под массив
    int size; // размер массива

    // Ввод количества элементов массива
    cout << "n = ";
    cin >> size;

    if (size <= 0) {
        // Размер масива должен быть положитлеьным
        cerr << "Invalid size" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    arr = new int[size]; // выделение памяти под массив

    // заполнение массива
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << "arr[" << i << "] = ";
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    int temp; // временная переменная для обмена элементов местами

    // Сортировка массива пузырьком
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++) {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                // меняем элементы местами
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    // Вывод отсортированного массива на экран
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    delete [] arr; // освобождение памяти;

    return 0;
}
```

Как теперь реализовать выполнение разности соседних элементов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так

```
for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++) {
    cout << (arr[i+1] - arr[i]) << " ";
}
```

А использовать стандартную библиотеку нельзя? с ней ваша задача решается в три строки:

```
vector<int> v;
copy(istream_iterator<int>(cin), istream_iterator<int>(), back_inserter(v));
sort(v.begin(),v.end());
adjacent_difference(v.begin(),v.end(),ostream_iterator<int>(cout,"\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int arr[10000], arr1[10000], n;

int main() {

//сout << "Введите количество элементов массива: ";
cin >> n;
//сout << "Введите элементы массива: ";
for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
    cin >> arr[i];
}
sort (arr, arr+n);

for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
    arr1[i]=arr[i+1]-arr[i];
}
return 0;
}
```

Как-то так. Легче и быстрее написать sort(), конечно.